# Can I create rule on AWS ELB so as to transfer all mobile traffic to another EC2/server

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile-website, amazon-elb

We do not have mobile app right now. We host mobile website on different EC2 instances. As of now I ELB which redirects traffic to nginx. We have logic on my nginx to identify mobile traffic and redirect to appropriate EC2 instance.

Is it possible to put a logic on ELB itself so as to redirect Mobile traffic to another EC2 instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon Elastic Load Balancer currently does not have redirect logic. It will only forward traffic to the EC2 instances behind the ELB.

To redirect to another EC2 instance, you'll need to do that processing at your nginx/EC2 instance layer.

Comment: Let me ask this way "if request coming from mobile; FORWARD the request to EC2 instance xyz" ...

Comment: Still no. ELB does not examine the request to detect a mobile device. It also has no way to "pick" a backend instance.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It can be done at nginx or at CDN level ( suppose if  you are using akamai cdn )